# Find $k$ if $f(x)=k(1/2)^x$ for $x=1,2,3,$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Find $k$ if $f(x)=k(1/2)^x$ for $x=1,2,3,$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Here is what I did:

$$\int_1^3 k\left(\frac12\right)^{x}dx=1$$
After integrating, I found it to be:

$$\left[\frac{-k}{ln(2)2^x}\right]_1^{3}=1$$
When I evaluated this I got $k=1.848$...which appears to be wrong as I was told $k=\frac87$

Did I do the integral wrong? How would you find the integral of $(\frac12)^x$? Or, is there some other error there?

Comment: Given the information provided, I would assume that the random variable is discretely distributed. Use a sum and you'll get the right answer.

Comment: You know what, you just may be right about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$f(1)+f(2)+f(3)=k\,\left(\frac12+\frac14+\frac18\right)=k\,\frac78$$

Comment: Thanks! After reading Marc's comment I knew immediately that I confused continuous and discrete.

Comment: Indeed you did.

Comment: I hope you 'did' that intentionally. =)